# Fix only the x-axis in ggplot facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have been using ggplot `facet_wrap` to separate the graph into different windows by measurement category.

I set the scales to "free" but that makes both the y and x axis scales flexible.

```
+ facet_wrap( ~measurementCategory, scales="free")
```

I want to let the y-axis scales be "free" as different measurement categories have different ranges.

But I want to keep my x-axis (which is a DateTime) scale "fixed".

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Does changing `scales = "free"` to `scales = "free_y"` work for you?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you. My bad for not reading the documentation.